# Question about Earthquakes

Tags: discussion

I would like to know are questions on earthquakes on-topic on this site?

For example, the devastating Earthquake of ASSAM INDIA in 1950 is rarely mentioned in Newspapers nowadays.

The book "CODE TO ZERO" is about the worst earthquake in Assam." ZERO" is a city now in "ARUNACHAL PRADESH" INDIA. This issue was grievous,north-easterners could not forget the disastrous past, now suppressed and hidden. This is my problem and concern too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions on earthquakes are on topic, there is an [earthquake tag](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthquakes) that will show you similar questions.

However, if the topic is about whether earthquake memory has faded, or whether there's some conspiracy to forget it in the media, that may well not fit the site.
The intention of thois EarthScience site is to address the physical phenomena themselves.  If you want to know more about the details of that earthquake, the potential for recurrence, or similar earthquakes, this site may well be able to help and it could make a great question.  But if you are only interested in discussing what happened or lamenting it being forgotten, it's unlikely to find place here.